# Deep zoom on dynamically generated 3D image cube

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom

I am making a 3D cube using kit3D.this cube is generated at run time.I wanted to know whether i will be able to add deep zoom o this dynamically generated 3D cube.The entire cube is ultimately an image and this is loaded altogather at a time.or is there any other way where in I can get the  deep zoom effect???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silverlight 2 this can't be done as we've not made allowances for a lot of perspective 3D transforms as we have in Silverlight 3.

In Silverlight 3 you should be able to perform this, but do remember that Deep Zoom is somewhat an adjustment to the end users UX, so zooming in and out on image sets whilst in a 3D face can be considered cumbersome if not handled appropriately.

**Scott Barnes / Rich Platforms Product Manager / Microsoft.**